# Получить данные из массива элемента

Tags: javascript, массивы

Только начал изучать angular.
И придумал задачу которую не могу решить.
Есть json файл, который получаем через `$http.get()`.

contact.json

```
{
  "countries":["Albania","Andorra","Armenia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Belarus","Belgium"],
  "cities": {
    "Albania": ["Tirana","Durrës","Vlorë","Elbasan","Shkodër","Korçë","Fier","Kamëz","Berat","Lushnjë","Sarandë","Paskuqan","Kavajë","Pogradec","Gjirokastër"],
    "Andorra": [...],
    "Armenia": [...],
    "Austria": [...],
    "Azerbaijan": [...],
    "Belarus": [...],
    "Belgium": [...]
},
  "users": {
 "Tirana": [
           {"name": "John Tomson", "phone": "+49 711 1325789"},
           {"name": "Evan Snouden", "phone": "+33 4 70038855"}
           ],
  "Durrës": [{...}],
  "Vlorë": [{...}],
  "Elbasan": [{...}],
  "Shkodër": [{...}],
  "Korçë": [{...}],
  "Fier": [{...}],
  "Kamëz": [{...}],
  "Berat": [{...}],
  "Lushnjë": [{...}],
  "Sarandë": [{...}],
  "Paskuqan": [{...}],
  "Kavajë": [{...}],
  "Pogradec": [{...}],
  "Gjirokastër": [{...}]
  }
}
```

И все получается кроме как вывести `users.name`.
Подскажите куда хотя бы смотреть?
`ng-repeat` - не помог.

```
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in data.users">
    {{user.name}}
    <li>
    </ul>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('/contact.json')
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала разбираете весь объект, полученный с `contact.json`.

Создаете новый массив `result` и добавляете туда то, что требуется вывести на странице.

Передаете новый массив шаблону.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('/contact.json')
    .success(function(data){
      var result = [];
      for(var names in data.users) {
          for(var name in data.users[names]) {
              result.push(data.users[names][name]);
          }
      }
      $scope.data = result;
    });
});
```

И печатаете.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in data">
    {{user.name}}
  <li>
</ul>
```